# Rails Migration : How to change the "foreign_key: true" to foreign_key: {to_table: ... } of a certain references column

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

i am kind of new to rails and My question is that how can i change a certain "foreign_key: true" to foreign_key: {to_table: ... } in a certain references column.

Example_FROM:

```
class CreateExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :examples do |t|
   t.references :test, foreign_key: true
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Example_TO:

```
class CreateExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :examples do |t|
   t.references :test, foreign_key: {to_table: :things}
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

a simple line of code on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution. i just simply deleted the columns of the foreign keys with remove_column and then added the new version of foreign keys with add_reference.

Hope it helps anyone who have the same problem :)